# An Error when showing group_path(@group)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Now, I tried to set up the route with group_path(@group) but got an error message like,

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /groups/%23%3CActiveRecord::Relation:0x007fd6cf362538%3E
Couldn't find Group with id=#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00fds6cf362538>
```

Here is my code. I would like to set up a link to groups/show/:id. Why did this error occur? Could you give me how to solve this?

☆index.html.erb

```
<% if @items.present? %>
      <% @items.each do |i| %>
      <% i_attr = i.get_element('ItemAttributes') %>
        <tr>
          <td> <%= link_to image_tag(i.get('SmallImage/URL'), {:style => 'border: none;'}), i_attr.get('DetailPageURL') %></td>
          <td> <%= link_to i_attr.get('Title'), i_attr.get('DetailPageURL') %></td>
          <td> <%= i_attr.get('Author') %></td>
          <td> <%= i_attr.get('PublicationDate')%></td>
          <td> <%= i_attr.get('Publisher') %></td>
          <td> <%= i_attr.get('NumberOfPages')%></td>
          <td>
              <% if @existing_groups_isbns.include? i_attr.get('ISBN') %>
                 <% @existing_groups_isbns.each do |isbn| %>
                   <% if isbn == i_attr.get('ISBN') %>
                      <% @group = Group.where(:isbn =>isbn) %>
                        <%= link_to '既存ページへ' , group_path(@group) %> 
                   <% end %>
                <% end %>
              <% else %><!-- if includes?==-->
                    <%= link_to '新規作成', {:controller => 'groups', :action => 'new', :name => i.get('ItemAttributes/Title'),:author => i.get('ItemAttributes/Author'), :publish => i.get('ItemAttributes/Publisher'), :published => i.get('ItemAttributes/PublicationDate'), :isbn => i.get('ItemAttributes/ISBN'), :page => i.get('ItemAttributes/NumberOfPages'), :imageurl=>i.get('MediumImage/URL')} ,class: "btn btn-midium btn-primary"%>
             <% end %><!--if  includes?--> 
          </td>
      </tr>  
  <% end %><!-- @items.each do-->
 <% else %><!--if @items.present?-->
    見つかりませんでした。
 <% end %><!-- if @items.present?-->
```

☆index_controller

```
  def index
    @keyword = params[:keyword]
    if @keyword.present?
      Amazon::Ecs.debug = true
      res = Amazon::Ecs.item_search(params[:keyword], 
          :search_index => 'All', :response_group => 'Medium')
      @items = res.items

    search_isbns = @items.map{ |isbns| isbns.get('ItemAttributes/ISBN')}

    search_asins = @items.map{ |asins| asins.get('ItemAttributes/ASIN')}
    @existing_groups_isbns = Group.select(:isbn).where(:isbn => search_isbns).map(&:isbn)
    @existing_groups_ids = Group.where(:isbn => search_isbns).map{|g| g.id}

   end
```

Comment: Did you restart after modifying the routes?  Also note the part "id=#<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00fds6cf362538>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<% @group = Group.where(:isbn =>isbn) %>
```

with

```
<% @group = Group.where(:isbn =>isbn).first %>
```

Because you need an object where you had an ActiveRecord relation

Comment: Mr.apneadiving, thank you very much!! Thanks to you, I could solve this.